# receber o que e escrito de um input

Tags: php, jquery

tenho a seguinte situação onde tenho esse input

```
<input type='text' class='form-control' value='' id='textInput'>
```

e tenho a span

```
<span date-dados='' class='j_details_action '></span>
```

o objetivo e pega o que e digitado no input e colocar dentro do atributo da span date-dados o codigo funciona mais o input esta dentro de um foreach onde pode ter mais de um input quando se tem dois input o java script funciona somente para o primeiro input . cada input tem uma span 
exemplo

```
<input type='text' class='form-control' value='' id='textInput'>
<span date-dados='' class='j_details_action '></span>
```

dentro de um foreach ficaria assim

```
<input type='text' class='form-control' value='' id='textInput'>
<span date-dados='' class='j_details_action '></span>

<input type='text' class='form-control' value='' id='textInput'>
<span date-dados='' class='j_details_action '></span>
```

ja tem o seguinte codigo em jquery

```
$('#textInput').on('keyup', function(){
  $(".j_details_action").attr("date-dados", $('#textInput').val());
```

});

Comment: Pode fazer isso apenas com JS/jQuery. PHP roda no lado do cliente e ele não te ajudará nesse problema. Já tentou fazer alguma coisa? Poderia [edit] e adicionar o código e descrever qual foi o resultado obtido?

Answer (score 4):

Você pode fazer isso utilizando javascript. Com o Jquery fica bem fácil de fazer, aqui tem um exemplo:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>One-way Data Binding com jQuery</title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Name:<input id="textInput" type="text"/>
    <br />
    <br />
    Olá <span id="nameDiv"></span>!
    <script>
      $('#textInput').on('keyup', function(){
        $('#nameDiv').html($('#textInput').val());
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Esse "date-dados" é um atributo de sua tag span que tem a classe "j_details_action". Seria interessante colocar um id neste elemento. Do jeito que está, para alterar ele seria desta forma:
$(".j_details_action").attr("date-dados", $('#textInput').val());